# An Identifiably Very Uncomplex Puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

This is a relatively easy puzzle, but I thought I might share it anyhow.

If 5 is 4, 6 is 9, and 7 is 5, what is 8?

Hint 1:

> The title gives a clue (not directly to the answer, but to the general rule.)

Hint 2:

> SPQR up!

Comment: Title has *identity* so perhaps it's $1$?

Comment: Edited Hint 1 for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that 8 =

> 1

because

> we are looking at Roman numerals embedded in the written-out form of the number's name. fIVe=IV=4, sIX=IX=9, seVen=V=5. So eIght=I=1.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a shot:

> 8 is **25**.

Reasoning:

> 'five' contains 4 letters
>  'six' contains 3 letters -> squared is 9
>  'seven' contains 5 letters
>  So basically just how many letters, and if the number is even, square it.

Comment: Not quite my reasoning, but close! The same, simple rule applies to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have that

> $8=8$

---

Explanation:

> $5$ has two lines and one curve. If the curve means 'subtract one line' then the result is $5$ minus $2-1$ which is $4$.

> Similarly, $7$ has two lines. The result is $7$ minus $2$ which is $5$.

> **So the rule for odd number is *odd number - (number of lines - number of curves)**

> **For the even numbers, it could just be that they are flipped upside-down, in which case $6$ is $9$ and $8$ remains the same.**

Comment: Not quite! But good try!